# Do Mobs spawn on Magma Blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do mobs spawn on Magma Blocks, because I recently got magma blocks but I'm not sure if mobs do spawn on them, as a matter of fact I wanted to create a mob farm if they do spawn on these blocks.

Answer (score 2):

As of Minecraft 1.10 Pre-Release 2, mobs doesn't spawn on magma blocks anymore. This was a bug in Minecraft 1.10 Pre-Release 1 and earlier Minecraft 1.10 versions, but it has been fixed.

**[See this bug on the Minecraft issue tracker.](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-102835)**